# Why does Ansible pre-task always skip?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to develop a playbook which could allow root to easily reset the password by running a playbook any time. But it alwasy skips the pretask which does the validation.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  remote_user: root
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo


  vars_prompt:

    - name: "root_password"
      prompt: "Enter your new root password"
      private: no
      when: root_password is not defined

  pre_tasks:

    - name: fail the play if the user missed out root_password
      fail: msg="root password should not be empty"
      when: root_password is not defined

  tasks:

    - name: Change root password
      user: name=root update_password=always password={{ root_password }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task is set to run when `root_password` is not defined and whatever value you enter, you do define it in the `vars_prompt` section. Hence the task is skipped.

Judging from the message you want to fail when it's empty, so the condition should be:

```
when: root_password == ""
```

Comment: ThankYou @techraf You have always been a saviour!

Comment: But I found out it never resets the password

Comment: @user_dev If you are running on a system different than macOS, you need to encrypt the password first. See [the manual](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/user_module.html).